# Azure: When Deploy FunctionApp to slot -> Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I'm using Azure DevOps and their CI/CD pipelines.
When I deploy my Windows FunctionApp to a slot I get this error:

```
2021-05-04T13:10:14.0501876Z ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
2021-05-04T13:10:14.0521125Z ##[error]Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.
```

Strangly there is no problem when I deploy the same release pipeline to production with this option "Deploy to Slot or App Service Environment" unchecked.
Since its working for production for me this is very weird...So do anybody have an idea whats going on?

Here a small log from kudu: (I removed the URI to the FunctionApp)
Note its not the full log since it was to large to post here

```
{
      "name":"2021-04-30T07-00-11_d9c8d9_001_Startup_POST_api-zipdeploy_0s.xml",
      "size":355,
      "mtime":"2021-04-30T07:00:11.9092333+00:00",
      "crtime":"2021-04-30T07:00:11.7981538+00:00",
      "mime":"text/xml",
      "href":"https://[FUNCTION_URI].scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/2021-04-30T07-00-11_d9c8d9_001_Startup_POST_api-zipdeploy_0s.xml",
      "path":"C:\\home\\LogFiles\\kudu\\trace\\2021-04-30T07-00-11_d9c8d9_001_Startup_POST_api-zipdeploy_0s.xml"
   },
   {
      "name":"2021-04-30T07-00-11_d9c8d9_002_POST_api-zipdeploy_202_1s.xml",
      "size":2079,
      "mtime":"2021-04-30T07:00:13.2111672+00:00",
      "crtime":"2021-04-30T07:00:11.9882903+00:00",
      "mime":"text/xml",
      "href":"https://[FUNCTION_URI].scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/2021-04-30T07-00-11_d9c8d9_002_POST_api-zipdeploy_202_1s.xml",
      "path":"C:\\home\\LogFiles\\kudu\\trace\\2021-04-30T07-00-11_d9c8d9_002_POST_api-zipdeploy_202_1s.xml"
   },
   {
      "name":"2021-04-30T07-00-12_d9c8d9_003_Background_POST_api-zipdeploy_2s.xml",
      "size":3653,
      "mtime":"2021-04-30T07:00:14.8463405+00:00",
      "crtime":"2021-04-30T07:00:12.7048044+00:00",
      "mime":"text/xml",
      "href":"https://[FUNCTION_URI].scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/2021-04-30T07-00-12_d9c8d9_003_Background_POST_api-zipdeploy_2s.xml",
      "path":"C:\\home\\LogFiles\\kudu\\trace\\2021-04-30T07-00-12_d9c8d9_003_Background_POST_api-zipdeploy_2s.xml"
   },
   {
      "name":"2021-04-30T07-00-20_d9c8d9_006_GET_api-deployments-temp-1de32b26_200_0s.xml",
      "size":1538,
      "mtime":"2021-04-30T07:00:20.2922484+00:00",
      "crtime":"2021-04-30T07:00:20.1491455+00:00",
      "mime":"text/xml",
      "href":"https://[FUNCTION_URI].scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/2021-04-30T07-00-20_d9c8d9_006_GET_api-deployments-temp-1de32b26_200_0s.xml",
      "path":"C:\\home\\LogFiles\\kudu\\trace\\2021-04-30T07-00-20_d9c8d9_006_GET_api-deployments-temp-1de32b26_200_0s.xml"
   },
   {
      "name":"2021-04-30T07-00-20_d9c8d9_007_GET_api-deployments-temp-1de32b26-log_200_0s.xml",
      "size":1684,
      "mtime":"2021-04-30T07:00:20.695538+00:00",
      "crtime":"2021-04-30T07:00:20.4833857+00:00",
      "mime":"text/xml",
      "href":"https://[FUNCTION_URI].scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/2021-04-30T07-00-20_d9c8d9_007_GET_api-deployments-temp-1de32b26-log_200_0s.xml",
      "path":"C:\\home\\LogFiles\\kudu\\trace\\2021-04-30T07-00-20_d9c8d9_007_GET_api-deployments-temp-1de32b26-log_200_0s.xml"
   },
   {
      "name":"2021-04-30T07-00-20_d9c8d9_008_GET_api-deployments-temp-1de32b26-log-03c43bf4-58c9-4ec9-b3c4-b703be6a4e0b_200_0s.xml",
      "size":1815,
      "mtime":"2021-04-30T07:00:21.0507931+00:00",
      "crtime":"2021-04-30T07:00:20.8726648+00:00",
      "mime":"text/xml",
      "href":"https://[FUNCTION_URI].scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/2021-04-30T07-00-20_d9c8d9_008_GET_api-deployments-temp-1de32b26-log-03c43bf4-58c9-4ec9-b3c4-b703be6a4e0b_200_0s.xml",
      "path":"C:\\home\\LogFiles\\kudu\\trace\\2021-04-30T07-00-20_d9c8d9_008_GET_api-deployments-temp-1de32b26-log-03c43bf4-58c9-4ec9-b3c4-b703be6a4e0b_200_0s.xml"
   },
   {
      "name":"2021-04-30T07-00-21_d9c8d9_009_PUT_api-deployments-51619766021863_200_1s.xml",
      "size":2182,
      "mtime":"2021-04-30T07:00:23.2713857+00:00",
      "crtime":"2021-04-30T07:00:22.0114824+00:00",
      "mime":"text/xml",
      "href":"https://[FUNCTION_URI].scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/2021-04-30T07-00-21_d9c8d9_009_PUT_api-deployments-51619766021863_200_1s.xml",
      "path":"C:\\home\\LogFiles\\kudu\\trace\\2021-04-30T07-00-21_d9c8d9_009_PUT_api-deployments-51619766021863_200_1s.xml"
   },
```

Edit: After even the support couldn't help me I deleted the ressource and created a new FunctionApp. Now its working as expected
.

Comment: Have you referred to the logs for more details?

Comment: You mean the log  from kudu? I edit my post